# Zendesk list endpoint is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, zendesk-api

I am facing issue with a listing of tickets and users. I am able to create a ticket but not able to list, I tried both options list and search but not working

Here is my code of list API

```
zendesk.tickets.list().then(function(tickets){
    console.log(tickets);
  });
```

Here is a Response header of list API

Request URL: https://task-me-not.zendesk.com/api/v2//tickets.json
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 35.174.158.178:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

I am using following library
https://github.com/dashedstripes/zendesk-node-api

Answer (score 0):

what's the response body that you're getting? 
And how are you executing?  From terminal running `node filename`, or something else?

I just tried this and it outputted my tickets just fine

```
var Zendesk = require('zendesk-node-api'); 
var zendesk = new Zendesk({ url: URL, email: EMAIL, token: TOKEN }); zendesk.tickets.list().then(function(result){
  console.log(result); 
});
```